# Meteor Fibers deprecated when deploying to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, meteor, buildpack, fibers

I'm deploying my Meteor application to Heroku using my [buildpack](https://github.com/jagi/heroku-buildpack-meteor) which used to work. I didn't make any deploy for a short time and today I have problem doing so. I get error when installing NPM dependencies. It says that there is problem with Fibers. Here is the log:

```
-----> Installing dependencies
child_process: customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead.
child_process: customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead.
       make: Entering directory `/tmp/build_70c8f25c1f62ee4cd50886dedb713437/.heroku/app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/build'
         CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o
../src/fibers.cc:222: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Arguments' with no type
../src/fibers.cc:222: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token
../src/fibers.cc:241: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Arguments' with no type
../src/fibers.cc:241: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token
../src/fibers.cc:279: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Arguments' with no type
../src/fibers.cc:279: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token
../src/fibers.cc:300: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Arguments' with no type
../src/fibers.cc:300: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token
../src/fibers.cc:468: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Arguments' with no type
../src/fibers.cc:468: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token
../src/fibers.cc:510: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'AccessorInfo' with no type
../src/fibers.cc:510: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token
../src/fibers.cc:518: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'AccessorInfo' with no type
../src/fibers.cc:518: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token
../src/fibers.cc:529: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'AccessorInfo' with no type
../src/fibers.cc:529: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token
../src/fibers.cc:533: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'AccessorInfo' with no type
../src/fibers.cc:533: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token
../src/fibers.cc:540: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'AccessorInfo' with no type
../src/fibers.cc:540: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token
../src/fibers.cc: In static member function 'static void Fiber::DestroyOrphans()':
../src/fibers.cc:202: error: no matching function for call to 'v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Persistent<v8::Value, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value> >&)'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:1899: note: candidates are: v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(const v8::String::Utf8Value&)
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:1889: note:                 v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Handle<v8::Value>)
../src/fibers.cc:210: error: 'class v8::Persistent<v8::Value, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value> >' has no member named 'Dispose'
../src/fibers.cc:213: error: 'class v8::Persistent<v8::Value, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value> >' has no member named 'Dispose'
../src/fibers.cc: In static member function 'static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Fiber::New(int)':
../src/fibers.cc:223: error: 'args' was not declared in this scope
../src/fibers.cc:224: error: 'New' is not a member of 'v8::String'
../src/fibers.cc:224: error: 'ThrowException' was not declared in this scope
../src/fibers.cc:226: error: 'New' is not a member of 'v8::String'
../src/fibers.cc:226: error: 'ThrowException' was not declared in this scope
../src/fibers.cc:229: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'v8::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::FunctionTemplate> >'
../src/fibers.cc:232: error: 'args' was not declared in this scope
../src/fibers.cc:233: error: 'GetCurrent' is not a member of 'v8::Context'
../src/fibers.cc: In static member function 'static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Fiber::Run(int)':
../src/fibers.cc:242: error: 'args' was not declared in this scope
../src/fibers.cc:248: error: 'New' is not a member of 'v8::String'
../src/fibers.cc:248: error: 'ThrowException' was not declared in this scope
../src/fibers.cc:250: error: 'New' is not a member of 'v8::String'
../src/fibers.cc:250: error: 'ThrowException' was not declared in this scope
../src/fibers.cc:260: error: 'AdjustAmountOfExternalAllocatedMemory' is not a member of 'v8::V8'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:6606: error: too few arguments to function 'v8::Handle<v8::Primitive> v8::Undefined(v8::Isolate*)'
../src/fibers.cc:269: error: at this point in file
../src/fibers.cc: In static member function 'static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Fiber::ThrowInto(int)':
../src/fibers.cc:280: error: 'args' was not declared in this scope
../src/fibers.cc:283: error: 'New' is not a member of 'v8::String'
../src/fibers.cc:283: error: 'ThrowException' was not declared in this scope
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:6606: error: too few arguments to function 'v8::Handle<v8::Primitive> v8::Undefined(v8::Isolate*)'
../src/fibers.cc:285: error: at this point in file
../src/fibers.cc:289: error: 'New' is not a member of 'v8::String'
../src/fibers.cc:289: error: 'ThrowException' was not declared in this scope
../src/fibers.cc: In static member function 'static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Fiber::Reset(int)':
../src/fibers.cc:301: error: 'args' was not declared in this scope
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:6606: error: too few arguments to function 'v8::Handle<v8::Primitive> v8::Undefined(v8::Isolate*)'
../src/fibers.cc:304: error: at this point in file
../src/fibers.cc:306: error: 'New' is not a member of 'v8::String'
../src/fibers.cc:306: error: 'ThrowException' was not declared in this scope
../src/fibers.cc:308: error: 'New' is not a member of 'v8::String'
../src/fibers.cc:308: error: 'ThrowException' was not declared in this scope
../src/fibers.cc:316: error: conversion from 'v8::Persistent<v8::Value, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value> >' to non-scalar type 'v8::Handle<v8::Value>' requested
../src/fibers.cc:317: error: 'class v8::Persistent<v8::Value, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value> >' has no member named 'Dispose'
../src/fibers.cc:319: error: 'ThrowException' was not declared in this scope
../src/fibers.cc: In member function 'void Fiber::UnwindStack()':
../src/fibers.cc:338: error: 'New' is not a member of 'v8::String'
../src/fibers.cc:352: error: 'class v8::Persistent<v8::Value, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value> >' has no member named 'Dispose'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:6606: error: too few arguments to function 'v8::Handle<v8::Primitive> v8::Undefined(v8::Isolate*)'
../src/fibers.cc:353: error: at this point in file
../src/fibers.cc:355: error: 'class v8::Persistent<v8::Value, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value> >' has no member named 'Dispose'
../src/fibers.cc: In member function 'v8::Handle<v8::Value> Fiber::ReturnYielded()':
../src/fibers.cc:383: error: conversion from 'v8::Persistent<v8::Value, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value> >' to non-scalar type 'v8::Handle<v8::Value>' requested
../src/fibers.cc:384: error: 'class v8::Persistent<v8::Value, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value> >' has no member named 'Dispose'
../src/fibers.cc:386: error: 'ThrowException' was not declared in this scope
../src/fibers.cc: In static member function 'static void Fiber::RunFiber(void**)':
../src/fibers.cc:396: error: expected initializer before '*' token
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:816: error: 'v8::HandleScope::HandleScope()' is protected
../src/fibers.cc:406: error: within this context
../src/fibers.cc:414: error: cannot convert 'v8::ResourceConstraints*' to 'v8::Isolate*' for argument '1' to 'bool v8::SetResourceConstraints(v8::Isolate*, v8::ResourceConstraints*)'
../src/fibers.cc:418: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'v8::Persistent<v8::Context, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Context> >'
../src/fibers.cc:422: error: 'New' is not a member of 'v8::String'
../src/fibers.cc:425: error: 'args' was not declared in this scope
../src/fibers.cc:427: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> >'
../src/fibers.cc:427: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'v8::Persistent<v8::Context, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Context> >'
../src/fibers.cc:429: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> >'
../src/fibers.cc:429: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'v8::Persistent<v8::Context, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Context> >'
../src/fibers.cc:446: error: 'AdjustAmountOfExternalAllocatedMemory' is not a member of 'v8::V8'
../src/fibers.cc:455: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'v8::Persistent<v8::Context, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Context> >'
../src/fibers.cc: In static member function 'static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Fiber::Yield_(int)':
../src/fibers.cc:470: error: 'New' is not a member of 'v8::String'
../src/fibers.cc:470: error: 'ThrowException' was not declared in this scope
../src/fibers.cc:476: error: 'ThrowException' was not declared in this scope
../src/fibers.cc:477: error: 'args' was not declared in this scope
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:6606: error: too few arguments to function 'v8::Handle<v8::Primitive> v8::Undefined(v8::Isolate*)'
../src/fibers.cc:478: error: at this point in file
../src/fibers.cc:482: error: 'New' is not a member of 'v8::String'
../src/fibers.cc:482: error: 'ThrowException' was not declared in this scope
../src/fibers.cc: In static member function 'static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Fiber::GetStarted(v8::Local<v8::String>, int)':
../src/fibers.cc:511: error: 'info' was not declared in this scope
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:6606: error: too few arguments to function 'v8::Handle<v8::Primitive> v8::Undefined(v8::Isolate*)'
../src/fibers.cc:512: error: at this point in file
../src/fibers.cc:514: error: 'info' was not declared in this scope
../src/fibers.cc:515: error: no matching function for call to 'v8::Boolean::New(bool&)'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:6194: note: candidates are: static v8::Handle<v8::Boolean> v8::Boolean::New(v8::Isolate*, bool)
../src/fibers.cc: In static member function 'static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Fiber::GetCurrent(v8::Local<v8::String>, int)':
../src/fibers.cc:520: error: conversion from 'v8::Persistent<v8::Object, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object> >' to non-scalar type 'v8::Handle<v8::Value>' requested
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:6606: error: too few arguments to function 'v8::Handle<v8::Primitive> v8::Undefined(v8::Isolate*)'
../src/fibers.cc:522: error: at this point in file
../src/fibers.cc: In static member function 'static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Fiber::GetPoolSize(v8::Local<v8::String>, int)':
../src/fibers.cc:530: error: no matching function for call to 'v8::Number::New(size_t&)'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:1999: note: candidates are: static v8::Local<v8::Number> v8::Number::New(v8::Isolate*, double)
../src/fibers.cc: In static member function 'static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Fiber::GetFibersCreated(v8::Local<v8::String>, int)':
../src/fibers.cc:541: error: no matching function for call to 'v8::Number::New(size_t)'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:1999: note: candidates are: static v8::Local<v8::Number> v8::Number::New(v8::Isolate*, double)
../src/fibers.cc: In static member function 'static void Fiber::Init(v8::Handle<v8::Object>)':
../src/fibers.cc:561: error: no matching function for call to 'v8::FunctionTemplate::New(v8::Handle<v8::Value> (&)(int))'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:3455: note: candidates are: static v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> v8::FunctionTemplate::New(v8::Isolate*, void (*)(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), v8::Handle<v8::Value>, v8::Handle<v8::Signature>, int)
../src/fibers.cc:562: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'v8::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::FunctionTemplate> >'
../src/fibers.cc:562: error: 'NewSymbol' is not a member of 'v8::String'
../src/fibers.cc:566: error: no matching function for call to 'v8::Signature::New(v8::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::FunctionTemplate> >&)'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:3698: note: candidates are: static v8::Local<v8::Signature> v8::Signature::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate>, int, v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate>*)
../src/fibers.cc:567: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'v8::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::FunctionTemplate> >'
../src/fibers.cc:570: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'v8::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::FunctionTemplate> >'
../src/fibers.cc:571: error: 'NewSymbol' is not a member of 'v8::String'
../src/fibers.cc:572: error: no matching function for call to 'v8::FunctionTemplate::New(v8::Handle<v8::Value> (&)(int), v8::Handle<v8::Value>, v8::Handle<v8::Signature>&)'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:3455: note: candidates are: static v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> v8::FunctionTemplate::New(v8::Isolate*, void (*)(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), v8::Handle<v8::Value>, v8::Handle<v8::Signature>, int)
../src/fibers.cc:573: error: 'NewSymbol' is not a member of 'v8::String'
../src/fibers.cc:574: error: no matching function for call to 'v8::FunctionTemplate::New(v8::Handle<v8::Value> (&)(int), v8::Handle<v8::Value>, v8::Handle<v8::Signature>&)'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:3455: note: candidates are: static v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> v8::FunctionTemplate::New(v8::Isolate*, void (*)(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), v8::Handle<v8::Value>, v8::Handle<v8::Signature>, int)
../src/fibers.cc:575: error: 'NewSymbol' is not a member of 'v8::String'
../src/fibers.cc:576: error: no matching function for call to 'v8::FunctionTemplate::New(v8::Handle<v8::Value> (&)(int), v8::Handle<v8::Value>, v8::Handle<v8::Signature>&)'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:3455: note: candidates are: static v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> v8::FunctionTemplate::New(v8::Isolate*, void (*)(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), v8::Handle<v8::Value>, v8::Handle<v8::Signature>, int)
../src/fibers.cc:577: error: 'NewSymbol' is not a member of 'v8::String'
../src/fibers.cc:580: error: no matching function for call to 'v8::FunctionTemplate::New(v8::Handle<v8::Value> (&)(int))'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:3455: note: candidates are: static v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> v8::FunctionTemplate::New(v8::Isolate*, void (*)(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), v8::Handle<v8::Value>, v8::Handle<v8::Signature>, int)
../src/fibers.cc:581: error: 'NewSymbol' is not a member of 'v8::String'
../src/fibers.cc:585: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'v8::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::FunctionTemplate> >'
../src/fibers.cc:587: error: 'NewSymbol' is not a member of 'v8::String'
../src/fibers.cc:588: error: 'NewSymbol' is not a member of 'v8::String'
../src/fibers.cc:589: error: 'NewSymbol' is not a member of 'v8::String'
../src/fibers.cc:592: error: 'NewSymbol' is not a member of 'v8::String'
../src/fibers.cc: In function 'void init(v8::Handle<v8::Object>)':
../src/fibers.cc:608: error: 'New' is not a member of 'v8::String'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:816: error: 'v8::HandleScope::HandleScope()' is protected
../src/fibers.cc:614: error: within this context
../src/fibers.cc: In function 'v8::Persistent<T, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T> > uni::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Handle<T>) [with T = v8::Object]':
../src/fibers.cc:123:   instantiated from here
../src/fibers.cc:30: error: no matching function for call to 'v8::PersistentBase<v8::Object>::New(v8::Isolate*&, v8::Handle<v8::Object>&)'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:572: note: candidates are: static T* v8::PersistentBase<T>::New(v8::Isolate*, T*) [with T = v8::Object]
../src/fibers.cc: In function 'v8::Persistent<T, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T> > uni::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Handle<T>) [with T = v8::Function]':
../src/fibers.cc:124:   instantiated from here
../src/fibers.cc:30: error: no matching function for call to 'v8::PersistentBase<v8::Function>::New(v8::Isolate*&, v8::Handle<v8::Function>&)'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:5809: note: candidates are: static T* v8::PersistentBase<T>::New(v8::Isolate*, T*) [with T = v8::Function]
../src/fibers.cc: In function 'v8::Persistent<T, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T> > uni::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Handle<T>) [with T = v8::Context]':
../src/fibers.cc:125:   instantiated from here
../src/fibers.cc:30: error: no matching function for call to 'v8::PersistentBase<v8::Context>::New(v8::Isolate*&, v8::Handle<v8::Context>&)'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:5809: note: candidates are: static T* v8::PersistentBase<T>::New(v8::Isolate*, T*) [with T = v8::Context]
../src/fibers.cc: In function 'void uni::Dispose(v8::Isolate*, v8::Persistent<T, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T> >&) [with T = v8::Object]':
../src/fibers.cc:136:   instantiated from here
../src/fibers.cc:34: error: 'class v8::Persistent<v8::Object, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object> >' has no member named 'Dispose'
../src/fibers.cc: In function 'void uni::Dispose(v8::Isolate*, v8::Persistent<T, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T> >&) [with T = v8::Function]':
../src/fibers.cc:137:   instantiated from here
../src/fibers.cc:34: error: 'class v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> >' has no member named 'Dispose'
../src/fibers.cc: In function 'void uni::Dispose(v8::Isolate*, v8::Persistent<T, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T> >&) [with T = v8::Context]':
../src/fibers.cc:138:   instantiated from here
../src/fibers.cc:34: error: 'class v8::Persistent<v8::Context, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Context> >' has no member named 'Dispose'
../src/fibers.cc: In function 'void uni::MakeWeak(v8::Isolate*, v8::Persistent<S, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<S> >&, P*) [with void (* F)(v8::Isolate*, v8::Persistent<v8::Value, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value> >, void*) = Fiber::WeakCallback, T = v8::Object, P = Fiber]':
../src/fibers.cc:146:   instantiated from here
../src/fibers.cc:39: error: 'class v8::Persistent<v8::Object, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object> >' has no member named 'MakeWeak'
../src/fibers.cc: In function 'v8::Persistent<T, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T> > uni::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Handle<T>) [with T = v8::Value]':
../src/fibers.cc:339:   instantiated from here
../src/fibers.cc:30: error: no matching function for call to 'v8::PersistentBase<v8::Value>::New(v8::Isolate*&, v8::Handle<v8::Value>&)'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:5809: note: candidates are: static T* v8::PersistentBase<T>::New(v8::Isolate*, T*) [with T = v8::Value]
In file included from /app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/src/node.h:61,
                 from ../src/coroutine.h:1,
                 from ../src/fibers.cc:1:
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h: In static member function 'static void v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::Uncompilable() [with O = v8::Object, T = v8::Object]':
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:592:   instantiated from 'static void v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::Copy(const v8::Persistent<S, M>&, v8::Persistent<T, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T> >*) [with S = v8::Object, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object>, T = v8::Object]'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:5826:   instantiated from 'void v8::Persistent<T, M>::Copy(const v8::Persistent<S, M>&) [with S = v8::Object, M2 = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object>, T = v8::Object, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object>]'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:657:   instantiated from 'v8::Persistent<T, M>::Persistent(const v8::Persistent<T, M>&) [with T = v8::Object, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object>]'
../src/fibers.cc:129:   instantiated from here
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:596: error: cannot convert 'v8::Primitive*' to 'v8::Object* volatile' in assignment
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h: In static member function 'static void v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::Uncompilable() [with O = v8::Object, T = v8::Function]':
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:592:   instantiated from 'static void v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::Copy(const v8::Persistent<S, M>&, v8::Persistent<T, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T> >*) [with S = v8::Function, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function>, T = v8::Function]'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:5826:   instantiated from 'void v8::Persistent<T, M>::Copy(const v8::Persistent<S, M>&) [with S = v8::Function, M2 = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function>, T = v8::Function, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function>]'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:657:   instantiated from 'v8::Persistent<T, M>::Persistent(const v8::Persistent<T, M>&) [with T = v8::Function, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function>]'
../src/fibers.cc:129:   instantiated from here
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:596: error: cannot convert 'v8::Primitive*' to 'v8::Object* volatile' in assignment
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h: In static member function 'static void v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::Uncompilable() [with O = v8::Object, T = v8::Context]':
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:592:   instantiated from 'static void v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::Copy(const v8::Persistent<S, M>&, v8::Persistent<T, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T> >*) [with S = v8::Context, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Context>, T = v8::Context]'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:5826:   instantiated from 'void v8::Persistent<T, M>::Copy(const v8::Persistent<S, M>&) [with S = v8::Context, M2 = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Context>, T = v8::Context, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Context>]'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:657:   instantiated from 'v8::Persistent<T, M>::Persistent(const v8::Persistent<T, M>&) [with T = v8::Context, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Context>]'
../src/fibers.cc:129:   instantiated from here
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:596: error: cannot convert 'v8::Primitive*' to 'v8::Object* volatile' in assignment
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h: In static member function 'static void v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::Uncompilable() [with O = v8::Object, T = v8::Value]':
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:592:   instantiated from 'static void v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>::Copy(const v8::Persistent<S, M>&, v8::Persistent<T, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T> >*) [with S = v8::Value, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value>, T = v8::Value]'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:5826:   instantiated from 'void v8::Persistent<T, M>::Copy(const v8::Persistent<S, M>&) [with S = v8::Value, M2 = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value>, T = v8::Value, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value>]'
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:664:   instantiated from 'v8::Persistent<T, M>& v8::Persistent<T, M>::operator=(const v8::Persistent<T, M>&) [with T = v8::Value, M = v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value>]'
../src/fibers.cc:339:   instantiated from here
/app/.node-gyp/0.12.0/deps/v8/include/v8.h:596: error: cannot convert 'v8::Primitive*' to 'v8::Object* volatile' in assignment
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o] Error 1
       make: Leaving directory `/tmp/build_70c8f25c1f62ee4cd50886dedb713437/.heroku/app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/build'
Build failed
```

Have you ever had problem like this? Do you know why is that happening?

Comment: Have you solved this?  Is there a general solution?  I have two projects: one that I am working on now which shows the same error as you are seeing, and another, archived one, that does not.  I am picking through slowly to see if I can localize the difference.  Hopefully we can help each other.

Answer (score 1):

I had been running my deployed Meteor app with ...

```
 nvm use unstable
 npm install
```

... the problem you show went away when I ran it with ...

```
 nvm use stable
 npm install
```

You might also try ,,,

```
 nvm use stable
 npm install -g node-gyp
 npm install
```

Comment: I will notify you about result in the next week because from today I will be out of computer.

Comment: Sorry for later response. I abandoned my project. By had to build it for last time for Heroku and the problem was with the Node version. The last version with which it worked was 0.10.36 and my build pack was downloading the newest one. However your approach should also work but haven't tested it.